# Android permissions to view data

Tags: android, permissions

I recently got interested in anything android.

I figured if you install apps on your android device, they have a lot of rights. 
This is pretty scary, at least i think.

A program like whatsapp is able to view and store and sent pretty much all of the device its information.

However my questions is, how can whatsapp view and copy and edit contacts, if the whole contacts thing ( stored in /data ) is root ? If i try to access the folders from my computer it gives me an error, that i do not have permission to view it.

So what in the whatsapp apk is used to extract the contact information from a root folder ?

I am very thankful for help !

Greetings,

Answer (score 1):

> So what in the whatsapp apk is used to extract the contact information from a root folder ?

Most likely, they use the [`ContactsContract` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) to read contact data. They hold the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, which allows them to use this API. They also hold the `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission, which allows them to modify contacts.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, there are public APIs that allow you to read Contact data. These require permissions.

A list of permissions can be found here:

[Android Manifest Permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

The permissions I imagine you are referring to are `READ_CONTACTS` and `WRITE_CONTACTS`. The actual data is accessed by a `Content Provider`. Content providers allow you to access data on the phone such as contacts, music, photos etc.

In WhatsApp's case, they will not be accessing any root folders, but using the Content Provider API which exposes the user's contacts.